# Retain previous value in Excel on cell error

Tags: excel, function

I'd like to have a way for a cell on a spreadsheet to retain its previous value if a new calculation has an error. As a simplified example:

```
    A   B   C
1   1   2   =A1/B1
```

Cell C1 will contain `0.5`. Now if I change B1 to `0`, I'd like C1 to stay at `0.5` instead of showing `#DIV/0!`. I've tried using the `IFERROR` function but it results in a circular reference.

I'd like this to work in a non-macro-enabled workbook.

Answer (score 2):

Easy....first enable iterative calculation with 1 max iterations in Excel options......then set up **A1**,  **B1** (as 2) and **C1** as in your example............then in D1:

```
=IF(ISERROR(C1),D1,C1)
```

Then set **B1 = 0**

**D1** will freeze up to the last non-error value if **C1** errs out.

**EDIT#1**:

Based on pnuts's comment:

```
=IF(ISERROR(A1/B1),C1,A1/B1)
```

can be placed in **C1** to achieve the exact behavior

Comment: @pnuts:  We could place **=IF(ISERROR(A1/B1),C1,A1/B1)** in **C1** to achieve that result, but there is no way to verify what is happening then.

Answer (score 1):

You either have to use the iteration calculation method (with all its downsides) or use something like the SpeedTools(costs, both 64 and 32-bit) Previous() function or MoreFunc(free, 32-bit only)  Recall() function. Both SpeedTools and MoreFunc are XLL addins, so do not require a macro-enabled workbook but require installing the XLL addin.

You can just about do this in a kludgy way using VBA and a macro-enabled workbook: see http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2012/01/08/writing-efficient-vba-udfs-part-8-getting-the-previously-calculated-value-from-the-calling-cells/

Disclaimer: I develop and sell the SpeedTools addin (works with 64-bit Excel, both 64 and 32-bit)